# Code not working to pass value from one form to another in Access 2017

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I have a form called `MortalityDataEntertyform4` containing a field `GoatID`.

I want to code to open the form `Goatforsalelist3` and populate field `GoatID2` with the value of `GoatID` from the form `MortalityDataEntertyform4`.

I tried the below code which opens the form but the values are not getting transferred:

```
Private Sub Command189_Click()
    Dim strFrmName As String
    strFrmName = "GoatForSaleList3"
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFrmName
    With Forms(strFrmName)
        Text165.Value = Me.Text78.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not getting an error message? Is form opening to a new record row?

Answer (score 1):

Need dot in front of control:

`.Text165 = Me.Text78`

`.Value` is not necessary although doesn't hurt to use.

If form is bound to data and textbox bound to field and form does not open to a New Record row, code will change value in existing record. So either set form DataEntry property to Yes or specify acFormAdd in OpenForm method:

`DoCmd.OpenForm strFrmName, , , , acFormAdd`

Then to further assure existing data is not altered:

`If .NewRecord Then .Text165 = Me.Text78`

Another approach is to use OpenArgs to pass value to second form then second form code uses OpenArgs to set its field/control value.